# how to "skip" php "exit" command?

Tags: php

I have following piece of code which I can't modify.

```
if ( empty($post->comment_status) ) {
            do_action('comment_id_not_found', $comment_post_ID);
            exit;
    }
```

I can create function called during `do_action` processing (hooks in wordpress).

```
function my_function () {
   //do something
}
add_action('comment_id_not_found', 'my_function');
```

Is it possible to skip the `exit;` command in the condition?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's obviously going to run as soon as `do_action` is executed - Why can't you change the code?

Comment: you can't override `exit()`, so why not force the comment_status to be non-empty?

Comment: Or you could throw some exception while having this code run in `catch` block...

Comment: @cthulhu that is an ugly solution... but I think it's probably the only one that would work.

Comment: @cthulhu you should post that as the answer

Comment: @Orangepill That's not an answer. He can't modify the original code and I fail to see how it could be wrapped in a try block if that's the case?

Comment: @RudiVisser He can hook in code that throws the exception and put the try/catch in the calling context..

Comment: @RudiVisser It is not known how is execution passed to the-code-that-cannot-be-modified. It is possible that somewhere along the way to that code there is code that **can** be modified.

Comment: @Cthulhu Reasonably assuming that his reasoning behind not being able to modify the code is because he does not want to touch the Wordpress source in any way; it is also reasonable to assume that he could not modify *any* part of the code relating to what was posted.

Comment: Well it is not necessary as it can be that he is calling some function from the code he cannot modify (why not? i am not particularly familiar with Wordpress, but in frameworks like Yii for example you often call functions supplied by framework immediately from your code). Anyway, I stated it in my answer (`That is, if you can put it in try-catch.`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exit` is a statement, there is no way to get around it and no way to modify it. The only way to avoid it is to make sure that your code doesn't pass by it. (eg. `if(FALSE) exit;` won't exit but in this: `do_something(); exit; do_something_else();` the function `do_something_else()` will not be called.)

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution said to be ugly would be to throw exception in you function while having all code you can't modify run in `try` block. That is, if you *can* put it in `try`-`catch`.